# Cannot disable SASS cache

Tags: css, caching, sass

I cannot prevent my `/.sass-cache` directory from being created.

I am attempting this by running:

`sass --no-cache`

However running that doesn't do anything. When I pull up the help flag, this is what I get:

```
Miscellaneous:
    -i, --interactive                Run an interactive SassScript shell.
    -c, --check                      Just check syntax, don't evaluate.
        --precision NUMBER_OF_DIGITS How many digits of precision to use when outputting decimal numbers.
                                     Defaults to 5.
        --cache-location PATH        The path to save parsed Sass files. Defaults to .sass-cache.
    -C, --no-cache                   Don't cache parsed Sass files.
        --trace                      Show a full Ruby stack trace on error.
    -q, --quiet                      Silence warnings and status messages during compilation.
```

After seeing this, I then tried `sass -C, --no-cache` but got this error:

> OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: -,   Use --trace for
>   backtrace.

How do I disable the creation of the `./sass-cache` folder?

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
sass -C
```

or

```
sass --no-cache
```

but not both.

If using `config.rb`, then add:

```
asset_cache_buster = :none 
cache = false
```

Comment: i use sass command on mac, version 1.26.8, there is no such cache option